# How can I get the name of the executing .exe?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

The Compact Framework doesn't support Assembly.GetEntryAssembly to determine the launching .exe. So is there another way to get the name of the executing .exe?

EDIT: I found the answer on Peter Foot's blog: http://peterfoot.net/default.aspx
Here is the code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_PATH * 2];

int chars = GetModuleFileName(IntPtr.Zero, buffer, MAX_PATH);

if (chars > 0)

{

string assemblyPath = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, chars * 2);

}

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]

private static extern int GetModuleFileName(IntPtr hModule, byte[] lpFilename, int nSize);
```

Comment: in CF2: string s = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether it works from managed code (or even the compact framework), but in Win32 you can call GetModuleFileName to find the running exe file.

[MSDN: GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
string exefile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
```

But if you put it in a DLL assembly, I believe it will give you the assembly file name.

The same call on the "Full" framework would return the .exe file with a "file:\" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

In managed code, i think you can use this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx

Application.ExecutablePath

Comment: Note that this solution is only for a Windows client application. If it's a console or a Windows Service, there will be no Application object.